# Reachability reports Wifi when HotSpot is On via USB

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, reachability, 3g

When I tether my mobile network to laptop with Hotspot on iPhone and test for Reachability's *currentReachabilityStatus* it reports **ReachableViaWiFi** where neither Wifi is open nor is it sharing mobile network via Wifi. 
I know even with this, it shows correct information on internet connectivity but the nature of my app requires exact information on whether Wi-fi is connected or not so its not the issue to determine internet connectivity but more of Wi-fi reachability.

x----x----x----x----x----x----x
EDIT:

Infact it fails if there is no device connected on USB. Only reports ReachableViaWiFi when a machine is using its internet via USB.

Answer (score 0):

Open this post: [detect hotspot enabling in iOS with private api's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220371/detect-hotspot-enabling-in-ios-with-private-apis)

Maybe enumerating network interfaces will let you discover the fact that connection is actually a tethered cellular network.

Don't worry that title includes private API - the solution contains also a way to this without using private API.