# How to detect any enabled hotspot in iOS with private APIs

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone-privateapi, hotspot, tethering

I want to detect whether the user has enabled hotspot/tethering on an iOS device. I can use private APIs, knowing it wont make it to the app store.

I was trying to go through [private APIs list/runtime headers](https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser/), but there are too many to decide which might be helpful. I'm trying to find where `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` gets fired from in private APIs (probably called for active call and activated hotspot, etc.)

I tried [detect personal hotspot](https://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/ios-detect-personal-hotspot/) and also used CaptiveNetwork, but it only returns the connected WiFi SSID, not the created hotspot.

With the above code the compiler shows the error

> SCDynamicStoreCreate is unavailable: not available on iOS.

So I went into SCDynamicStore.h and changed the following:

```
SCDynamicStoreRef
SCDynamicStoreCreate    (
    CFAllocatorRef          allocator,
    CFStringRef         name,
    SCDynamicStoreCallBack      callout,
    SCDynamicStoreContext       *context
)

__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_1,__IPHONE_NA);
```

to:

```
SCDynamicStoreRef
SCDynamicStoreCreate    (
    CFAllocatorRef          allocator,
    CFStringRef         name,
    SCDynamicStoreCallBack      callout,
    SCDynamicStoreContext       *context
)           

__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_1,__IPHONE_6_0);
```

Now I am able to get the dictionary with the states 1022 and 1023.

By changing the file like this, will I have any problem in archiving the build (or any other problem) other than the fact that we know this code won't make it to the app store?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Without Private APIs

You can detect active personal hotspot by enumerating network interfaces using C APIs. When hotpost is active and someone is connected to it there will be interface with `bridge` prefix. On my iPhone 5 it's `bridge100`. If hotspot is disabled or no one is connected to it that interfaces will not even be in the list.

C APIs will even return you IP address and subnet mask in that network.

That's what I'm using in my applications to detect active hotspot.

To get SSID you need `[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]` - personal hotspot SSID always matches device name.

### With Private APIs

You can obtain all the information about personal hotspot using this code:

```
SCDynamicStoreRef sc = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, CFSTR("com.apple.wirelessmodemsettings.MISManager"), NULL, NULL);
NSDictionary* info = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(sc, CFSTR("com.apple.MobileInternetSharing"));
CFRelease(sc);
```

`info` dictionary will look something like this when hotspot is active and has connections:

```
{
    Errnum = 0;
    ExternalInterfaces =     (
        "pdp_ip0"
    );
    Hosts =     {
        Current = 1;
        Max = 5;
        MoreAllowed = 1;
        Type =         {
            AirPort = 0;
            Bluetooth = 0;
            Ethernet = 0;
            "USB-Ethernet" = 1;
        };
    };
    InternalInterfaces =     (
        bridge100
    );
    Reason = 0;
    State = 1023;
    Version = 2;
}
```

When hotspot is active but there are no connections:

```
{
    Errnum = 0;
    ExternalInterfaces =     (
    );
    Hosts =     {
        Current = 0;
        Max = 5;
        MoreAllowed = 1;
        Type =         {
            AirPort = 0;
            Bluetooth = 0;
            Ethernet = 0;
            "USB-Ethernet" = 0;
        };
    };
    InternalInterfaces =     (
    );
    Reason = 0;
    State = 1023;
    Version = 2;
}
```

When hotspot is not active:

```
{
    Errnum = 45;
    ExternalInterfaces =     (
    );
    Hosts =     {
        Current = 0;
        Max = 5;
        MoreAllowed = 1;
        Type =         {
            AirPort = 0;
            Bluetooth = 0;
            Ethernet = 0;
            "USB-Ethernet" = 0;
        };
    };
    InternalInterfaces =     (
    );
    Reason = 0;
    State = 1022;
    Version = 2;
}
```

`State` key will  be equal to `1023` when hotspot is active regardless of active connections. I don't know whether that value contains bit-flags or not. iOS is actually checking if value is equal to `1023`.

SCDynamicStore APIs are from public `SystemConfiguration` framework but marked as not available on iOS platform. That means all the headers are there, you just need to copy definitions without `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING` macro.

You can even observe changes to that setting - you can specify a key which value you want to observe. Read Apple documentation for implementation details.

> So I went into SCDynamicStore.h and changed the following

I wouldn't do that. It shouldn't cause any problems but for me changing SDK headers is not a good solution. I suggest the following. Don't include the framework headers. Make your own header where you copy all the methods you need with `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING` changed or removed.

Comment: How is that different from the OP's "detect personal hotspot" link?

Comment: @JesseRusak, I gave a full answer to his question including SSID of the hotspot. The code in the link uses wrong interface name. As you can see, looking for `bridge0` is wrong - on newer devices it's called `bridge100`. We need to look just for the prefix `bridge`.

Comment: great. it worked. i am also getting bridge100 as of now. but i was still wondering if i could get the hotspot active status irrespective of the fact that no one has connected to that hotspot yet?

Comment: @creker i have updated the question, have another query so we can hopefully close it

Comment: Hi,I try to using your code to get the hotspot info. But I get below error. 'SCDynamicStoreCreate' is unavailable: not available on iOS.  And other error below 'SCDynamicStoreCopyValue' is unavailable: not available on iOS. Have any method to resolve  above problem? My try these code in xcode6.4.iOS SDK 8.4. Thank you very much.

Comment: @dickfala, I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: @creker , thank for your response. I'm not very understand. Can you explain how to do and changed you mention detail method ? You meaning we should copy the SCDynamicStore.h and copy into to project and changed or delete manually?I try to delete have show __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING method?But they are still not found the SCDynamicStoreCreate .sorry, I'm stupid. But I really want to achieve the function. Can you help me ,please.thanks

Comment: Hi @creker, I had post my complete problem at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621847/ios-how-to-detect-hotspot-turn-on-in-ios8
Can you help me? thank you.

Comment: How to "enumerating network interfaces using C APIs", could you please post the code?

Comment: found it, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748480/swift-get-devices-ip-address