# 'SCDynamicStoreCreate' is unavailable: not available on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, hotspot

I am working on an app, where I am trying to detect mobile Hotspot. I googled about this and trying to implement that. I imported

```
#include <SystemConfiguration/SCDynamicStore.h>
```

and tried this code,

```
SCDynamicStoreRef sc = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, CFSTR("com.apple.wirelessmodemsettings.MISManager"), NULL, NULL);
NSDictionary* info = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(sc, CFSTR("com.apple.MobileInternetSharing"));
```

I am getting error in both lines,

```
'SCDynamicStoreCreate' is unavailable: not available on iOS
'SCDynamicStoreCopyValue' is unavailable: not available on iOS
```

How can I solve this?(XCode version 8.2.1)

Comment: Those are only available for Mac OS.

Comment: @MidhunMP any alternative for this, if it is not available??

Answer (score 0):

Create a header file with exact content as that of `SCDynamicStore.h`. Remove all entries of `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING`. Import this new header instead of `<SystemConfiguration/SCDynamicStore.h>`.

That should do.

I learned this from @crecker's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222196/770817).