# Modify Headers of SCDynamicStore.h in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to detect Hotspot status in iOS. For that I need to use the `SystemConfiguration` APIs as follows

```
let sc = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, "com.apple.wirelessmodemsettings.MISManager" as CFString, nil, nil)
let info = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(sc, "com.apple.MobileInternetSharing" as CFString)
```

But `SCDynamicStoreCreate` and `SCDynamicStoreCopyValue` are not available for iOS. I need to modify `SCDynamicStore.h` file and make these functions available for iOS (They are currently marked available for Mac only).

This link mentions a way to do this by creating duplicate header.. [SCDynamicStoreCreate is unavailable: not available on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998035/scdynamicstorecreate-is-unavailable-not-available-on-ios). But this method is not working for me in swift.

How this can be achieved in swift?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do this.

Here's a way that is all Swift and does not involve altering header files.

```
    import SystemConfiguration

    // Define types for each of the calls of interest
    typealias TSCDynamicStoreCreate = @convention (c) (_ allocator: CFAllocator?, _ name: CFString, _ callout: SystemConfiguration.SCDynamicStoreCallBack?, _ context: UnsafeMutablePointer<SCDynamicStoreContext>?) -> SCDynamicStore?
    typealias TSCDynamicStoreCopyValue = @convention (c) (_ store: SCDynamicStore?, _ key: CFString) -> CoreFoundation.CFPropertyList?

    // Get a handle to the library, the flag `RT_NOLOAD` will limit this
    // to already loaded libraries
    let hLibrary = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration", RTLD_NOLOAD);

    // Load addresses of the functions from the library
    let MySCDynamicStoreCreate = unsafeBitCast(dlsym(hLibrary, "SCDynamicStoreCreate"), to: TSCDynamicStoreCreate.self)
    let MySCDynamicStoreCopyValue = unsafeBitCast(dlsym(hLibrary, "SCDynamicStoreCopyValue"), to: TSCDynamicStoreCopyValue.self)

    // Setup constants
    let name = "com.apple.wirelessmodemsettings.MISManager" as CFString
    let key = "com.apple.MobileInternetSharing" as CFString

    // Call the functions through the looked up addresses
    let dynamicStore = MySCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, name, nil, nil)
    let plist = MySCDynamicStoreCopyValue(dynamicStore, key)
    dump(plist)
```