# How to know if the network state is WiFi hotspot on iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking, reachability

Now I can just recognize WiFi/2G/3G/4G, but when the state is WiFi hotspot, `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` or `Reachability` also recognize the state as WiFi. Please help me to achieve this requirement, thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect hotspot enabling in iOS with private api's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220371/detect-hotspot-enabling-in-ios-with-private-apis). This question does also include an answer which doesn't use private APIs.

Comment: @RemcoBeugels That question is about detecting whether a hotspot is enabled on the current phone.  I think the OP is asking about detecting whether the current phone is connected to a hotspot (vs a proper Access Point).

Answer (score -2):

I had found the right way:

```
- (void)startMonitorWifiChange {
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                    NULL,
                                    &onNotifyCallback,
                                    CFSTR("com.apple.system.config.network_change"),
                                    NULL,
                                    CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
}
static void onNotifyCallback(CFNotificationCenterRef center,
                             void *observer,
                             CFStringRef name,
                             const void *object,
                             CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
    if (CFStringCompare(name, CFSTR("com.apple.system.config.network_change"), kCFCompareCaseInsensitive) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        //TODO when wifi changed
        [[BaiduLocationManager sharedManager].baiduLocationManager requestNetworkState];
    }
    else {
        NBLog(@"intercepted %@", name);
    }
}
- (void)stopMonitorWifiChange {
    CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                       NULL,
                                       CFSTR("com.apple.system.config.network_change"),
                                       NULL);
}
```